# Is early April a peak tourist season for national park areas in the southwest US?

Tags: usa, national-parks

I will be joining family members on a round-trip tour of national parks in the southwest US in early April, and in order to make travel more flexible we'd prefer not to book lodging in advance if we can. Will traveling in early April make booking lodging difficult due to high demand?

Our [route](https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=17WW2pBlwQHEET_LraLGsBTvaSnM&ll=37.08408673000522%2C-111.83296359375004&z=8) consists of traveling through, and staying in the areas around:

- Las Vegas
- Hoover Dam
- Grand Canyon National Park
- Marble Canyon
- Horseshoe Bend
- Antelope Canyon
- Monument Valley
- Glen Canyon National Rec. Area
- Capitol Reef National Park
- Arches National Park
- Bryce Canyon National Park
- Dixie National Forest
- Zion National Park
- Parashant National Monument
- Valley of Fire State Park

Comment: No, April is not peak season.

Comment: Keep in mind that some hotels inside the national parks may not yet be open, so you might be looking at lodging outside.  But none of the parks you are considering is that large to make driving in each day that bothersome.

Comment: It's highly variable.  At one extreme, the North Rim of the Grand Canyon will still be closed for the winter and Bryce Canyon is still ramping up for summer; at the other extreme, Zion is reasonably active and Death Valley (where you aren't going) will be winding down from peak season.

Answer (score 2):

The  National Park Service Visitor Use Statistics [website](https://irma.nps.gov/Stats/SSRSReports/Park%20Specific%20Reports/Visitation%20by%20Month?Park=GOGA) provides monthly statistics including visitor data for all national parks.

An examination of the data for parks in the southwest indicates April is generally not among the top three months by visitor traffic and hence not peak season thus by extension booking during those periods should not be too difficult.